# How to implement Qt4 widgets written in C++ into some Python code?

Tags: c++, python, qt4, pyqt4

In I my attempts at creating a GUI (a document viewer) with PyQt4, failing reproduce the quality of existing programs, it has been suggested I should use those existing program's Qt4 Widgets (Okular's to be precise), rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Fair enough, but those Qt4 widgets are written in C++: how am I supposed to call them from the Python side? And does it require me to learn C (in which case I'd rather put more time in figuring out a fully Pythonic solution)?

Comment: Corrected questions as Mata pointed out Qt is written in C++, and not C as I first had assumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Qt` isn't written in C, its's written in C++, and so is [`Okular`](https://projects.kde.org/projects/kde/kdegraphics/okular/repository).

Unfortunately getting C++ libraries to work with python is not as easy as using C libraries through `ctypes`. To do that, you'll need to write some wrapper code around the C++ APIs to get it working.
Some ways to do that:

- [`sip`](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/sip/intro) - used by PyQt
- [`shiboken`](http://www.pyside.org/docs/shiboken/) - used by PySide
- [`cython`](http://wiki.cython.org/WrappingCPlusPlus) can also be used to wrap C++, don't know if it plays well with Qt

Comment: OK. So supposing I need a module from Okular, say a PDFViewer widget, I can simply follow [the C++ example on the SIP documentation](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/sip4/using.html#a-simple-c-example). Then after creating those scripts, I could simply import the modules and their class as if those were written in Python? It sounds too good to be true.

Comment: yes, however you'll still have to write all the sip definition code.